# Javascript - exporting function from a module

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a global function in one script from another script.
This is the first script called `subpage.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  shopButtons();

  //hide store buttons in alex box on subpages
  if (window.location.pathname.includes('/subpage')) {
    $('.js-alex-box-store-buttons').hide();
    var element = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    scrollToElement('#' + element);
  }
});
```

And this is the other script called `subpage-scroll.js`:

```
function scrollToElement(element) {
  if($(element) && $(element).offset()) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 80
    });
  }
}

$( '.anchor-links' ).click(function() {
  var element = $(this).attr('id').split('-');

  if (element[0] == 'download') {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
  }
  else {
    scrollToElement('#' + element[0]);
  }
});
```

I am bundling all scripts into one `app.js` script in this order:

```
require('./subpage-scroll');
require('./subpage');
```

But when I navigate to `subpage` I get an error:

> get Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollToElement is not defined

Why do I get when I have declared the function as a global and I am requiring the script where the function is before the script where I use it?

**Update**

I have tried with by making new file `scroll-to-element.js`:

```
exports.scrollToElement = function(element) {
  if($(element) && $(element).offset()) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 80
    });
  }
}
```

And then I have removed the function `scrollToElement`from  `subpage.scroll.js` and just required it in `subpage.js` and `subpage.scroll.js` by adding at the top of the scripts:

```
var scrollToElement = require('./scroll-to-element');
```

And then I am using the function: `scrollToElement.scrollToElement()`

Comment: Modules are not globally scoped. Meaning, you don't get global values just by declaring functions as you would with regular script files.

Comment: could you show the resulting js file ?

Comment: it is a huge file, since I have bundle other files as well

Comment: I am not sure but I think it is just the standard node require function, and then it is webpack that bundles them

Comment: Modules are not globally scoped - as @adam-beck said. In your case, to acess `scrollToElement ` globally - define it in window object.

`window.scrollToElement =  function(element) {
  if($(element) && $(element).offset()) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - 80
    });
  }
}`

Comment: `var s = require('./scroll-to-element')`  this will give you an object. You have to access the method with `s.scrollToElement()`.

You can use multiple export in your module file i.e) `exports.func1 = function(){}; exports.func2(){}`. When you require, it will give you export object. Eg:  `var s = require(file_url);   s.func1();    s.func2()`